# How to Line Break in a Calculation in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I am inserting a calculation into my form which is trying to compile all of the selections made up to this point (like a summary sheet).  I'm using an if statement for each possibility (if x option is selected list it, otherwise null)

```
=  (if ChooseAnExteriorStyle.StartsWith("Urban") then ("Urban Exterior Style  " + ChooseAnExteriorStyle_Amount) else (null)) +
   (if ChooseAnExteriorStyle.StartsWith("Cott") then ("Cottage/Cabin Exterior Style  " + ChooseAnExteriorStyle_Amount) else (null)))
```

The results look like:

> Urban Exterior Style  $3000Cottage/Cabin Exterior Style $4000

How do I make it look like:

> Urban Exterior Style  $3000
>
> Cottage/Cabin Exterior Style $4000

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with Cognito Forms. Unfortunately, you cannot insert a new line using a calculation field. However, you can use a content field to produce your desired format. If you used calculation fields to produce the correct text for each selected exterior style then you could reference/insert those fields in a content field to produce your summary.

[image]

[image]